# Trouble adding Mapper as dependency in a Lift project

Tags: scala, orm, dependencies, lift

I am doing my first Lift project and want to add a database. Following a book, I added the following dependency to build.sbt:

> "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile",

And then, in Boot.scala, the import

> import net.liftweb.mapper._

Now the project doesn't compile, with Boot.scala giving the error

> object mapper is not a member of package net.liftweb

But other sources around the Internet seem to suggest that my imports are OK.

Where does the dependency problem come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this is a problem of Eclipse, which cannot setup the dependencies correctly.

I had to close the project in Eclipse and delete the hidden files .classpath and .project. Then get into SBT and run

> eclipse 
>   (the project has to use the sbteclipse plugin as described in the Lift cookbook). This recreates the project files with the correct dependencies.

Afterwards, Eclipse compiled the code as expected. It seems this will be needed every time a change is made to build.sbt.